# Export 2 min QuickTime movie clip in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, quicktime

I want to know how to export a 2 minute QuickTime movie in Cocoa.

Comment: Can you give a bit of context?  Are you on a mac or the iphone, what is the source of this video - a camera, another video, a screencap or procedurally generated?  What do you want to export it to - QuickTime or a different format, and where do you want to send it - email, web, file, display?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Mac OS X Apple provides the QTKit.framework which offers convenient access to QuickTime's core functionality.
As you didn't provide any details in your question, I assume you want to export a 2 minute long sequence of a longer QuickTime movie on Mac OS X:
The "Making an Edit" section of Apple's ["Using the QTKit framework"](http://developer.apple.com/quicktime/qtkit.html) explains how to trim an existing movie and export the result.